# Simple Android Table formating Own widgets

Tags: android, layout, formatting

historically i have stupid problems with layouts, and now i try to fill this blank in my brain. Watch this example, i try to do some axis for graphic, and i want to pack them like this:

Vertical line by left side
Horizontal line by bottom
Spacer between Vert & Horiz in left bottom corner
Other place fill by graph
(Sorry not allowed to post images.I hope you see graphics axis before, no need to explain.)

And this what i got at now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.example.graphicformatting.Axis
        android:id="@+id/yaxis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:background="@color/backpanel_dark"
        custom:ishorizontal="false" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="This text field mean my own graphic widget, which not have any OnMeasured function or any specific and it&apos;s painting with size, which assigment by parent/ Just use getHeight and getWeight" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <View
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/backpanel_dark" />

    <com.example.graphicformatting.Axis
        android:id="@+id/yaxis"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:background="@color/backpanel_dark"
        custom:ishorizontal="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is code of my axises:

```
package com.example.graphicformatting;

public class Axis extends View {

public static final int HORIZONTAL = 0;
public static final int VERTICAL = 1;
public static final int DP_SIZE = 40;

int type = -1;
int size;
Paint painter;

public Axis(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.com_example_graphicformatting_Axis);
    final int N = a.getIndexCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        int attr = a.getIndex(i);
        switch (attr) {
        case R.styleable.com_example_graphicformatting_Axis_ishorizontal:
            if (a.getBoolean(attr, true)) {
                type = HORIZONTAL;
            } else
                type = VERTICAL;

            break;
        default:
            Log.d("axis", "Found unexpected state");
        }
    }
    a.recycle();
    final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    size = (int) (DP_SIZE * scale + 0.5f);
    painter = new Paint();
    painter.setColor(Color.RED);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    if (type == HORIZONTAL) {
        this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, size);
        this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(parentWidth, size));
        // Log.d("axis", "Size of horizontal calc: " + (parentWidth) + " "
        // + size);
    } else if (type == VERTICAL) {
        this.setMeasuredDimension(size, parentHeight);
        this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size, parentHeight));
        // Log.d("axis", "Size of vertical calc: " + size + " "
        // + (parentHeight));
    } else { // Для нормального отображения в конструкторе
        this.setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
        this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size, size));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (type == VERTICAL) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, size, getHeight(), painter);
    } else {
        canvas.drawRect(0, getHeight() - size, getWidth(), getHeight(), painter);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

How to custom my Layouts to get right pic? 
Ou, this using for set horizontal/vertical attribute (value/attrs.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="com.example.graphicformatting.Axis">
    <attr name="ishorizontal" format="boolean"></attr>
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```